# $(window).resize(); doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a problem with window.resize . My code js/jquery is here

```
var x = $(window).width();
var y = $(window).height();
var z = $('#card').height();
var a = z + 140; // !!!zmienic gdy zmiana marginesu z gory lub paddingu (100 margin + 20x2 padding)
var b = 1.78 * y;
var c = 1.78 * a;
function updateBodySize(){
    x = $(window).width();
    y = $(window).height();
    z = $('#card').height();
    a = z + 140; // !!!zmienic gdy zmiana marginesu z gory lub paddingu (100 margin + 20x2 padding)
    b = 1.78 * y;
    c = 1.78 * a;
    if (c>b) {
        if (x>c) {
            $('body').css({'background-size': x + 'px auto'});
        }
        else {
            $('body').css({'background-size': 'auto ' + c + 'px'});
        }
        $('body').css({'height': a + 'px'});
    }
    else {
        if (x>b) {
            $('body').css({'background-size': x + 'px auto'});
        }
        else {
            $('body').css({'background-size': 'auto ' + b + 'px'});
        }
        $('body').css({'height': y + 'px'});
    }
}
$(document).ready(updateBodySize()); //kiedy zaladowany
$(window).resize(updateBodySize());  //kiedy zmiana rozmiaru
```

Comments are in Polish but they aren't important. I want to run function updateBodySize every time browser is resized, but now this function runs only when document is ready (so i know that function works correct) (line last but one) and it looks like the last line is ignored. Is this line wrong `$(window).resize(updateBodySize());`? Or is something worng with my function? I checked this code in Chrome 33.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your final two lines seem to be the problem here:

```
$(document).ready( updateBodySize() );
$(window).resize( updateBodySize() );
```

Should be:

```
$(document).ready( updateBodySize );
$(window).resize( updateBodySize );
```

Note the dropping of the `()` from `updateBodySize` - your aim is to pass the *function* `updateBodySize` to `.ready` and `.resize`, not its *result*. By call the function instead, what you're doing is passing the result of `updateBodySize()` to the `.ready` and `.resize` functions, in effect:

```
$(document).ready( null );
$(window).resize( null );
```

Which, as you've noticed, does nothing except what `updateBodySize()` does first (two) times you called it. Drop the `()` and it will be treated as the event handler you expect.

**PS**:

Unless you're using the first block of

```
var x = $(window).width();
var y = $(window).height();
var z = $('#card').height();
var a = z + 140;
var b = 1.78 * y;
var c = 1.78 * a;
```

before your function block, you can drop it, since you redefine those var *inside* the function, so it'll calculate them independantly any time it's called.

Comment: Thanks, now everything works :) But I'm wondering why this function worked one time after page was loaded if I put the result to `$(document).ready();`, not function itself.

Comment: It happens (twice, actually) when the page is loaded because your original code called the function twice: once in `.ready( updateBodySize() )` and once in `.resize( updateBodySize() )`. Each of these *first* ran the function, *then* passed the result of the function on to the method.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use this, because the way you are doing it, the function is executed and the return value of the function is set as the callback function, which will not work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    updateBodySize();
}); //kiedy zaladowany
$(window).resize(function() {
    updateBodySize();
});  //kiedy zmiana rozmiaru
```

Comment: You're right, but you can probably also do `$(document).ready(updateBodySize);` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(window).resize(updateBodySize());
});
```

Comment: Not necessary! `$(window)` is always working, even when the page is not fully loaded, as `window` is defined before rendering.

Comment: It's not necessary and it's also wrong: as explained in the approved answer, passing the result of updateBodySize (by calling updateBodySize()) won't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){updateBodySize();}); //kiedy zaladowany
$(window).resize(function(){updateBodySize();});
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could try this:

window.onresize = updateBodySize;